# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Hibernate works, but needs 40 seconds to start again

Tags: hibernate, resume

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS and would like to use the hibernate function. 
The computer has got 8 GB Ram and I created a swap-partition of the same size on the PCIe-SSD. I already added the entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mmcblk0p3"` to the config-file of grub. 
`systemctl hibernate` works well, the computer 'switches off' and after a reactivation it continues where it stopped working. I also can see during the start process that the swap-dumps are read.

BUT: The system takes 35 seconds to start, a 'real' power-off takes 40 seconds. 
After hibernate the computer starts completely from scratch: I can see the logo of the motherboard-manufacturer, the grub-menu and so on. 
Is this behaviour correct? I expected the system to re-start within a few seconds?

(I am not using a GUI!)

Comment: well you are reading 8GB from the SSD to RAM

Comment: The /dev/mmcblk0p3 name does not look like a PCIe SSD. If you're using a board with an emmc, copying 8GB of data from your flash to your RAM will be slow like that

Comment: It should be `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, I just copied the command from another website because I didn't remember the correct name of the grub-entry (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`). 
In fact the ssd is a WD Black PCIe SSD WDS256G1X0C)